# How can I convert lon, lat coordinates to x, y?

Tags: shapely, machine-learning

For machine learning, I need to convert an array of coordinates in lon, lat format to simple floats where x=0,y=0 will be a most southwest coordinate and x=1,y=1 most northeast, and x=0.5,y=0.5 will be coordinate in a center.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 12):

### Update

If `utm` coordinates are suitable for your purposes, then note that in lieu of `pyproj`, the [`utm`](https://github.com/Turbo87/utm) package is now available and is simpler to use. Just be aware of `lng`, `lat` ordering vs. `easting`, `northing` ordering for the respective `from_latlon` and `to_latlon` functions, per the docs.

The below conversion example would become:

```py
import utm
x, y = utm.from_latlon(input_lat, input_lon)
```

### Original

Use `pyproj` for converting your lng, lat pairs to a projected coordinate system. In other words you need to convert from your geographic coordinate system (most likely EPSG code 4326) to a local projected coordinate system, e.g. a local UTM zone or regional system such as the British National Grid (EPSG code 27700).

```
import pyproj as proj

# setup your projections
crs_wgs = proj.Proj(init='epsg:4326') # assuming you're using WGS84 geographic
crs_bng = proj.Proj(init='epsg:27700') # use a locally appropriate projected CRS

# then cast your geographic coordinate pair to the projected system
x, y = proj.transform(crs_wgs, crs_bng, input_lon, input_lat)
```

Note that `pyproj.transform()` also works on numpy arrays, so you can therefore transform your lon, lat arrays to x, y arrays. You can then use numpy's built-in array methods to normalise your values.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min())
y = (y - y.min()) / (y.max() - y.min())
```

However, if you are using `sklearn` already, then you may as well use [sklearn.preprocessing.normalize](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what metric you need to preserve. One obvious approach is to project it to some appropriate flat coordinate system. To do this, you can use the `pyproj` library. Then, simply rescale your coordinates to be in the range [0, 1]. However, this doesn't perfectly preserve spatial relationships because longitude and latitude are on a sphere (or an ellipsoid or geoid), and x,y coordinates are on a flat surface. You should read about different map projections to see what you may be losing. A good reference is [Map Projections: A Working Manual](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395). If your positions only cover a small patch of the Earth, the errors may be acceptable to you.

A second approach is to convert the longitude and latitude to (x, y, z) coordinates in 3d space. If you approximate the earth's surface as a sphere, then the formulae should be

```
x = sin(pi/2-lat) * cos(lon)
y = sin(pi/2-lat) * sin(lon)
z = cos(pi/2-lat)
```

where `lon` and `lat` are in radians. In this case however, z=-1 is the south pole, z=1 is the north pole, x=1 and x=-1 are the prime meridian, and the dateline, and y=1 and y=-1 are 90 degrees East and 90 degrees West. Again, you can rescale so that coordinates are [0,1] rather than [-1,1].

Answer (score 2):

just use gdal.ApplyGeoTransform adn gdal.InvGeoTransform.Here's the python code:

```
src = gdal.Open(filename)
#if the file contains GeoTransform
geotrans = src.GetGeoTransform()
#if the file contains only GCPs
gcps = src.GetGCPs()
geotrans = gdal.GCPsToGeoTransform(gcps)

#from pixel coordinate to lat/lon
lat, lon = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(geoTrans, x,y)

# from lat/lon to pixel coordinate
invTs = gdal.InvGeoTransform(ts)
x, y = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(invTs, lat, lon)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have `lon = -1.7063, lat = 55.4127`.

Actually for bored ones method is:

```
import utm
x, y, zone, ut = utm.from_latlon(input_lat, input_lon)
```

which will give you

```
581902.0344218995 6141479.109914647 30 U
```

but note, **pyproj** is faster and some times more precise according to my tests.